# Cannot load file path for files with Node.js Server and Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, three.js

I'm having difficulty loading 3D models from a folder on my computer, using a localhost node.js test server, with three.js library.

app.js: (I run it via command line in the project directory using: `node app.js` command)

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var THREE = require('three');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Relevant portion of index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index.html title</title>

</head>

<body>
    
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
<script src="//threejs.org/build/three.js"></script> 
<script src="//threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/AMFLoader.js"></script>
<script src="//threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<script>
    
    var socket = io();
    
    var camera, scene, renderer;

    init();

    function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x999999 ) );
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500 );
        camera.up.set( 0, 0, 1 );
        camera.position.set( 0, -9, 6 );
        camera.add( new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 ) );
        scene.add( camera );
        var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 25, 1.0, 0xffffff, 0x555555 );
        grid.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ), 90 * ( Math.PI/180 ) );
        scene.add( grid );
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
        renderer.setClearColor( 0x999999 );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        
        /* everything up till here works */

        var loader = new THREE.AMFLoader(); 
        loader.load('/models/rook.amf', function ( amfobject ) { //'./models/rook.amf'

            scene.add( amfobject );
            render();

        } );

        /* ^^^ this is the part not working */

        var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
        controls.target.set( 0, 1.2, 2 );
        controls.update();
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    }
    function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        render();
    }
    function render() {    
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My project directory:

[image]

The error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/models/rook.amf 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I properly load files with Node and three.js on my simple server test?

Answer (score 2):

Right now, your web server is not serving the `models` directory. You can serve it, however, by asking express to static-ly serve the `models/` directory like this:

```
app.use(express.static('models'));
```

See more: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm getting the error `app.use(express.static('models'));
        ^

ReferenceError: express is not defined`. Any ideas?

Comment: Add a line to the top: `var express = require('express')`

Comment: I did, but still get the error as the original question, `GET http://localhost:3000/models/rook.amf 404 (Not Found)` (and yes, the file is definitely there in models lol)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use `express.js`. Express.js has a module for serving static assets (https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static).

Here is an example using that module:

```js
var express = require('express');
var THREE = require('three');


var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'models')); //Express static file module


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This website has documentation on this module: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Your html files don't have to be changed.

Comment: The person who asked the question was already using express...

Comment: @JDS I updated my answer by adding `__dirname`.Try it now